# get MySQL table results rows as columns

Tags: mysqli, row, multiple-columns

I have a table like this

[image]

and i want a 1 query that reference_id = 1 and reference fields equal to title and alias and introtext

expected result:
title  -> හැඳින්වීම

alias  -> overview-si

introtext ->

ධීවර

is it possible? and how can I get it ?

Comment: its a common query , you can learn by google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have refence id and that three reference_field values, use

```
SELECT reference_field,value FROM tbl_name WHERE reference_id=1 AND ( reference_field='title' OR reference_field='alias' OR reference_field='introtext)
```